# How can one determine if script has been included in a Web Worker?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I'd like to set up my library to "just work" as a Web Worker if spun up in a `new Worker()`. To do so I need to attach an event listener on `self` to receive messages.

If my script has been included inside another developer's Web Worker using an `importScripts()`, how do I know when I'm a third party and should not attach an event listener on self to receive messages?

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this using [WorkerGlobalScope](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/workers.html#the-global-scope):

```
if (typeof WorkerGlobalScope !== 'undefined' && self instanceof WorkerGlobalScope) {
    // code
} else {
    // code
}
```

ie, you may check for the absence of `document` to check you're in a worker.

Also the [specs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/workers.html#apis-available-to-workers) says that:

> The DOM APIs (Node objects, Document objects, etc) are not available
>   to workers in this version of this specification.

Comment: The way I've read the spec, and what from I've seen so far testing, is that an included script will also have a reference to self. If that's the case, and self always points to a `WorkerGlobalScope` per the spec link (key word: "global"), I'm confused as to how this helps me determine whether I am the third party.